# Session not working in Flask code when I send request from Ajax (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, ajax, session, flask

I created a **session** with the user's email id in **flask (python framework),** after the user login his account. Ok, its work fine and session created as I cross checked it. The url for it is `"http://localhost:5000/login"`. But, when the user click **logout** button from browser, I found that the **session is not working**.. (I do not know, though I created the session at time of login).

My ajax code runs on **apache2 server** as `"http://localhost:80/index.html"`.

When I cross check by using **curl**, its works fine. But, in the case of browser, when I click on **logout** button, there is message which I found on **terminal (ubuntu)** that **your session expired** though, I created at the time of **login**.

Here, **Ajax code** for **login** part of **index.html**

```
// Login ajax python
            $("#btn_login").click(function(){
                var txt1 = $("#txt1").val();
                var txt3 = $("#txt3").val();
                console.log("text: ", txt1, txt3);
                var a = {"username": txt1, "password": txt3, "type": "login"};
                $.ajax(
                    {
                        url: "http://localhost:5000/login",
                        type: "POST",
                        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
                        data: JSON.stringify(a),
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(response) {
                            console.log("Response from Python: ", response);
                            var output = response.result;
                            $("#show_msg").html("Mengego says: " + output.message + " " + output.user);
                        },
                        error: function(err) {
                            console.log("error: " + err);
                        }
                    }
                );
            });
```

Below is **Ajax code** for **logout** part of **index.html**

```
// Logout 
            $("#logout").click(function(){
                $.ajax(
                    {
                        url: "http://localhost:5000/logout",
                        type: "POST",
                        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
                        success: function(response) {
                            console.log("Response from Python: ", response);
                            var output = response.result;
                            $("#show_msg").html("Output of Logout: " + output.message);
                        },
                        error: function(err) {
                            console.log("error: " + err);
                        }
                    }
                );
            });
```

Below is **flask code** for **login** part of **"user.py"**

```
@user_api.route("/login", methods=['POST'])

def login():

    returning_data = {}
    try:
        form_params = request.json
        username = form_params["username"]
        password = form_params["password"]
        sql = "SELECT username, password FROM user WHERE username = '" + username + "' AND password = '" + password + "'"
        results = obj_connect.executeFetch(sql)
        if len(results) == 0:
           returning_data = { "message": "You enter incorrect username or password..", "user": []}
        else:
           sql = "SELECT email FROM user WHERE username = '" + username + "' AND password = '" + password + "'"
           results = obj_connect.executeFetch(sql)
           # session creation 
           session['email'] = results[0][0]
           print "session key is ", session['email']
           print "session is ", session
           session.permanent = True
           returning_data = { "message": "Welcome!!!...", "user": username}
    except Exception:
        print traceback.format_exc()
        returning_data = { "message": "Error during Login" }
    return jsonify({"result": returning_data})


Below is flask code for logout part of **"user.py"**

@user_api.route("/logout", methods=['POST'])
def logout():
    print "ses", session
    returning_data = {}
    try:
        if 'email' in session:
            print "your session is alive"
        else:
            print "your session expired"
        session.clear()
        if 'email' in session:
            print "your session is still alive"
        else:
            print "your session already expired"
        returning_data = { "message": "You are Logout Now...." }
    except Exception:
        print traceback.format_exc()
        returning_data = { "message": "Failure in Logout" }
    return jsonify({"result": returning_data})
```

---

Now, in the above code of flask for **logout** part, I got the following output on **terminal** (ubuntu), when I **click** the logout button from browser....

**Current Wrong Output :**

```
your session expired
your session already expired
```

**Expected Output:**

```
your session is alive
your session already expired
```

Please, help me for this..

Answer (score 0):

You should be storing information in the Flask global object to retain information throughout the lifetime of each request and the request object to get information sent with each request.

```
from flask import g, request
```

This way you can check the `g` object for values on it (as it's a dictionary) and then login/logout based on set values.

For example: 
`g.session = "session key"` when you're logging in, and then `g.session = None` when you're logging out.

**Note:** This assumes that you are checking login credentials from a database or some set value within the flask app before processing a request.

Answer (score -2):

Try including the following option in your Ajax Request:-
optionxhrFields: { withCredentials: true }